# Add info about time to acceptance into the /accepted-answer page in the help centre

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, help-center

If someone wants to know what the time limit is for acceptances, they need to come here and search in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). That's suboptimal - not everyone even knows about the existence of main meta, and this sort of vital info should be self-contained on a given site and its help centre.

The logical place to look would be in the [accepted-answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) page in the help centre, but the info isn't there.

**Please could info about allowed times for acceptances be included in the help centre?**

Another short paragraph to say this would be great:

> You can only accept an answer after 15 minutes have elapsed from the time you posted the question. This time limit is raised to 48 hours if the answer is your own.

Comment: It's in the rate limit guide, under "Accepting".

Comment: @ShadowWizard Where does the purported dupe target include a **feature-request for including this information in the help centre**, which is what this question is? Voted to reopen.

Comment: that is a part of rate limiting. The user can only accept an answer after x minutes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The question is not about the time itself, it is about adding this information in the help center ...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not asking a support question - I'm asking for this information to be **included in the help centre**. I *know* I can find it here on meta - that's not the issue.

Comment: @Tensibai it wasn't clear in the original question. Now it is, reopened.